# How to login to Iserv Schoolserver by using requests (symfony)

Tags: python-3.x, symfony, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How can you login to iserv with requests?
Cant find anything for Iserv on the internet

***EDIT:***

For anyone interested, I wrote a python module now:

[gitlab.com/schoolserver_redo_project/iservscrapping](https://gitlab.com/schoolserver_redo_project/iservscrapping)

You can install using pip:

`pip3 install iservscrapping`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you once got it, its easy:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'_username': 'user.name', '_password': 'yourpass'}

session = requests.Session()
print(session.post('https://iserv-demo.de/iserv/login_check', headers=headers, data=payload))
# Now we are logged in and can get anything we have access to by using session.get
res = session.get("https://iserv-demo.de/iserv/plan/show/raw/02-Vertreter%20Sch%C3%BCler%20morgen/subst_002.htm")
# Optionally parse it with bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```